# pandas calculate new values (new columns) from existing values matching date indexed values in 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, multiple-columns, calculated-columns

I'd like to apply a function per team in date sequence with distinction if they HomeTeam or AwayTeam. I'd like to store this value in a new column for each team in turn. For example:
when Everton plays home its ratio of goals scored vs goals scored against over 5 sliding window games at home.
The data frame looks like this:

|  | Date | HomeTeam | AwayTeam | FTHG | FTAG | FTR | HTHG | HTAG | HTR | HS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1250294400000000000 | Aston Villa | Wigan | 0 | 2 | A | 0 | 1 | A | 11 |

here is the code I'm struggling with:

```
slider = 5
df=data_games.copy()
team='Everton'
#diff_goals:
def difference(row):
    goals = 0
    if row['HomeTeam'] == team:
        goals = row['FTHG']
        y = row['FTAG']
    elif row['AwayTeam'] == team:
        row['AwayTeam'] == team
        goals = row['FTAG']
        y = row['FTHG']
    return (goals - y)


df['difference'] = df.apply(difference, axis=1).rolling(min_periods=1, window=slider).mean().convert_dtypes('Int')
```

of course I want to do this from a list of teams either playing home or away
so at the end I'll have a data frame with columns added for each calculation for each team's value for this function for 5 games in a row... I'm sure there is a better way of doing it by slicing the original data frame with possibly Groupby but I'm not sure how the date would behave as it is important to keep the games in sequential order. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may be looking for a `groupby` here, with the rolling mean applied to the groups

Comment: running: df['difference'] = df.groupby('AwayTeam').apply(difference).rolling(min_periods=1, window=match_glissant).mean().convert_dtypes('Int')
it says: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!

Comment: @Chris after setting the date as index for the data frame I got this to work: 
df['difference'] = df[team_filt].apply(lambda x: x['FTHG'] - x['FTAG'], axis=1).rolling(min_periods=1, window=slider).sum().convert_dtypes('Int') where the team_filter is a filter on say 'Everton' but the values in the resulting data frame column 'difference' make no sense (first 10 records show -5 (Everton lost 6-1 to Arsenal somewhere in that boolean filter 'True' but why is this value populated to other games ? It fits for all games played that day ?

Comment: ok got it to work finally...solution is:
a) set index to double values of 'date' and 'away team' to work on home team
`df = data_games.copy()`
`df.set_index((["Date","AwayTeam"]), inplace=True)`

b) define a filter (as I want to work from a list of team in a loop)
`team_filt = (df["HomeTeam"] == 'Everton')`

c) run the function to apply to the selected 'HomeTeam'
`slider = 5`
`df['difference'] = df[team_filt].apply(lambda x: x['FTHG'] - x['FTAG'], axis=1).rolling(min_periods=1, window=slider).sum().convert_dtypes('Int')`

Thanks, I'm sure there's a better way but it works.